# Parse XML into collection of Payments containing Invoices using LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Assume I have the following XML structure. Payments are applied to Invoices. A Payment can contain one or more Invoices. I would like to parse this XML into a collection of Payment objects that in turn contain a collection of Invoice objects. How can I write a LINQ statement that would populate a collection of Payment objects with the associated Invoices? Preferably in lambda syntax style.

```
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <PaymentId>Payment123</PaymentId>
        <PaymentAmount>120.00</PaymentAmount>
        <Invoice>
            <Id>InvoiceABC</Id>
            <InvoiceAmount>50.00</InvoiceAmount>
        </Invoice>
        <Invoice>
            <Id>InvoiceDEF</Id>
            <InvoiceAmount>60.00</InvoiceAmount>
        </Invoice>
        <Invoice>
            <id>InvoiceGHI</id>
            <InvoiceAmount>10.00</InvoiceAmount>
        </Invoice>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <PaymentId>Payment456</PaymentId>
        <PaymentAmount>57.50</PaymentAmount>
        <Invoice>
            <Id>InvoiceJKL</Id>
            <InvoiceAmount>57.50</InvoiceAmount>
        </Invoice>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <PaymentId>Payment789</PaymentId>
        <PaymentAmount>95.25</PaymentAmount>
        <Invoice>
            <Id>InvoiceMNO</Id>
            <InvoiceAmount>85.00</InvoiceAmount>
        </Invoice>
        <Invoice>
            <Id>InvoicePQR</Id>
            <InvoiceAmount>10.25</InvoiceAmount>
        </Invoice>
    </Payment>
</Payments>
```

Class objects

```
public class Payment
{
  public string PaymentId {get; set;}
  public decimal PaymentAmount {get; set;}
  public List<Invoice> Invoices {get; set;}
}

public class Invoice
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public decimal InvoiceAmount {get; set;}
}
```

I have can parse the XML but I get stuck on how to group into the object collection

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponse);
List<Payment> paymentsCollection = xml.Descendants("Payments")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Payments` in the root node, you should get `Payment` nodes with `Descendants` method.You can do the following using `Descendants`, `Element` and `Elements` methods:

```
var query=paymentsCollection.Descendants("Payment")
                            .Select(p=>new Payment{
                                       PaymentId=(string)p.Element("PaymentId"),
                                       PaymentAmount= (decimal)p.Element("PaymentAount"),
                                       Invoices=p.Elements("Invoice")
                                                 .Select(i=> new Invoice{
                                                              Id=(string)i.Element("Id"),
                                                              InvoiceAmount=(decimal)i.Element("InvoiceAmount")
                                                             }
                                                        ).ToList()
                                      }
                                   ).ToList();
```